# Поиск комбинации текста C#

Tags: c#, text

Есть список тайтлов окон: List titles; Необходимо перебрать и отобрать те тайтлы в которых содержиться опеределенный кусок текста.

```
Например список окон: 
Как приучить собаку к улице - chrome;
Купить книгу - chrome;
Новая папка;
Безымяный - Блокнот;
```

Надо отобрать 2 окна со словом "chrome".

Comment: Вопрос в перечислении окон или в поиске подстроки в строке?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вопрос и в том и в том, нужно перебрать список тайтлов окон и оставить те, в которых есть слово "chrome". Неужели не понятен вопрос изначально ? зачем задавать такие глупые вопросы ?

Comment: А что вы уже пытались сделать сами? Если вы не знаете как искать подстроку - вам нужно почитать книжки, тогда вы справитесь сами. Тут не сервис написания кода за других.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов пытался найти метод, который сможет такое сделать. Алгоритмом я и сам напишу, через поиск в масиве. Хотелось узнать, есть ли способ менее ёмкий. А если Вы такой умный, то это сервис "Вопрос - Ответ", а не умников, которые задают глупые вопросы, вместо помощи.

Comment: И что, не нашли поиск подстроки в строке? Тогда за вас придется весь код писать, а это точно не "вопрос ответ".

Comment: Для поиска окон именно Хрома стоит не пользоваться подстроками или чем-бы то ни было — они ненадёжны, а найти процесс, соответствующий окну, и проверить его путь.

Comment: @EvgeniyKhoduley На самом деле вам ведь задали вполне нормальный вопрос, который помог бы уточнить подход решения задачи (т.е. его можно решить вообще другим путем, без всяких поисков по строке), вы просто среагировали на него как на жесткую критику, а у автора вряд ли были такие намерения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск подстроки: `string1.IndexOf(substring1)`. Другой способ: `string1.Contains(substring1)`.

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответ, именно то, что и искал)